# The calling thread must be STA

Tags: wpf

The error Im getting :
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

So I have an android application which generates a bill of materials on the server side. Therefore a new UI has to be generated for the bill of materials. When I try to add a product to the BOM..this is the error I am getting. How do I go about it. An solution allowing me to host the service the android application is using is already running. The BOM application is a part of this solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183622/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new thread in your application, set its apartement state like in the code below before you start it:

```
            Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
            {

            });

            myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            myThread.Start();
```

If you do not create new Threads like this you may have to declare you "main" or "startup" -method with an [STAThread] - attribute. See here: [Why does WPF require a STAThread attribute to be applied to the Main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293402/why-does-wpf-require-a-stathread-attribute-to-be-applied-to-the-main-method)