# WHY do we need to call control.invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

1. It is well-known that threads share the same address space.
2. Also it is well known that we cannot directly update UI from different thread(we have to use `control.Invoke` instead).

So my question is WHY this UI objects(label, textbox etc.) are so special ? Why we can set some properties or call some methods for usual classes, but cannot do it for UI classes ?

Comment: This is how WPF is designed. It assumes that all UI calls are within the same thread.

Comment: @helb This isn't about WPF per-se. It's in the fact UI elements in windows are COM objects. And COM is thread-affine, meaning you can only "touch it" from the thread which created it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293402/why-does-wpf-require-a-stathread-attribute-to-be-applied-to-the-main-method

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN :

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is designed to save developers
>   from the difficulties of threading. As a result, the majority of WPF
>   developers won't have to write an interface that uses more than one
>   thread. Because multithreaded programs are complex and difficult to
>   debug, they should be avoided when single-threaded solutions exist.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:

As an answer to your comment -

> "Does your quote explains something ???!!"

I thought it was clear enough:

You -

> my question is WHY this UI objects(label, textbox etc.) are so special ? Why we can set some properties or call some methods for usual classes, but cannot do it for UI classes ?

MSDN -

> Because multithreaded programs are complex and difficult to debug, they should be avoided when single-threaded solutions exist.

I deleted the second paragraph, I didn't notice I copied it too.

Comment: Does your quote explains something ???!!

Comment: @Disappointed Please see my edit. I thought you were asking why .NET forces single threaded UI.